# Eclipse- Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: windows, tomcat6

I was trying to configure tomcat6 in eclipse. After configure tomcat in eclipse i have started server. It shows below error messages,

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

After searching Google i checked with ports in command prompt. but none of the applications running in this port as below,

```
C:\>netstat -an | find "9000"

C:\>netstat -an | find "8005"

C:\>netstat -an | find "8009"

C:\>
```

Anything am i missed? If anything wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It means those ports are not available at that time. There might be chance of having tomcat server in your PC, So try to Change the port numbers by double clicking on your apache server in servers tab. then your apache tomcat will run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed you ip recently, the entry for localhost in the hosts file is invalid. Update the ip in your hosts file.